# Loop through listbox and add to textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, listbox

I have a listbox that I am trying to read through all the data in it and put those values in a textbox. I thought I this would use a for loop but it only runs once and then quits.

```
var listbox = $('#<%=listBox.ClientID%>'); 
for (var count = 0 ; count <= $('#<%=listBox.ClientID%>').length; count++) {
    var existing = $('#<%=stringTextBox.ClientID%>').val();
    var value = listbox[count].value; 
    document.getElementById("<%=stringTextBox.ClientID%>").value = "," + value + existing
}
```

Comment: Because `$('#<%=listBox.ClientID%>')` Will be a unique ID!

Answer (score 0):

First: `#<%=listBox.ClientID%>` is an selector by ID. The idee of IDs is that there is always at most one element with this ID.

Second: `var value =` should be something like `var value = $(<listboxselector>).get(count).val()`